# swift - Method does not override any method from its superclass & 'UITableView' does not have a member named 'viewDidLoad'

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I am very new to swift and when I say new, I mean I just started this morning, I am having an issue I tried googling for but can't seem to find a solution.

I have this swift file:

```
import UIKit

class ProntoController: UITableView {

    var tableView:UITableView?
    var items = NSMutableArray()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
    }

    func viewWillAppear(animated: Bool) {

        NSLog("Here")

        let url = "API.php"

        NSURLSession.sharedSession().dataTaskWithURL(NSURL(string: url)!) { data, response, error in
            NSLog("Success")
        }.resume()
    }

    func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        return 1
    }

    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return self.items.count;
    }

    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        var cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("CELL") as? UITableViewCell

        return cell!
    }


}
```

My problem is with this section of code:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
    }
```

I get these two errors:

```
'UITableView' does not have a member named 'viewDidLoad'
Method does not override any method from its superclass
```

Comment: If you're familiar with programming, but not with Swift, I'd recommend taking a peek at Stanford's CS193P course on iTunesU. https://web.stanford.edu/class/cs193p/cgi-bin/drupal/

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to subclass `UITableViewController`, you're subclassing `UITableView`

Comment: This creates a new error with this line `var tableView:UITableView?`  `Setter for 'tableView' with Objective-C selector 'setTableView:' conflicts with setter for 'tableView' from superclass 'UITableViewController' with the same Objective-C selector`, `Getter for 'tableView' with Objective-C selector 'tableView' conflicts with getter for 'tableView' from superclass 'UITableViewController' with the same Objective-C selector` & `Cannot override with a stored property 'tableView'`

Comment: remove `tableView` definition from your custom class, its already inherited from `UITableViewController`